# Web Part "Chrome Type" property

Tags: 2013, web-part

After adding a web part I always need to change the Chrome Type property from "default" to "none".  Is there a way to make the default value be "none"?

> Web Part properties > Appearance > Chrome Type: Default

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make the change in the webpart **element.xml** file

```
<property name="ChromeType" type="chrometype">None</property>
```

Comment: Would he have to do that for every type of web part? Could you apply for adding libraries/lists to a web part page? Or is there a way to change it for every web part in the entire farm or site collection?

Comment: This is for each webpart of the same type. For farm, site collection wide, I would have to look.

Answer (score 0):

Bah, won't let me comment without 50 rep.  In SP2013, when deploying via VisualStudio, I had to put the tag you gave in the .webpart file, not the elements file for the webpart.

Example:
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<webParts>
  <webPart xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v3">
    <metaData>
      <type name="ConnectWebParts.Announcements.Announcements, $SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$" />
      <importErrorMessage>$Resources:core,ImportErrorMessage;</importErrorMessage>
    </metaData>
    <data>
      <properties>
        <property name="Title" type="string">Announcements</property>
        <property name="Description" type="string">Home Page Announcements Part</property>
        <property name="ChromeType" type="chrometype">None</property>
      </properties>
    </data>
  </webPart>
</webParts>`